# Why file extension validator does not work?

Tags: 7, files, forms

Created this based on doc comments: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_validate_extensions/7
My upload field definition:

```
   $form['xml'] = array(
        #'#title' => t('Upload Document XML'),
        '#type' => 'file',
        '#description' => t('We process only XML files'),
        '#upload_location'    => "public://documents/",
        "#upload_validators"  => array("file_validate_extensions" => array("xml")),

    );
```

But every file type passed in...

Any suggestions, please?

Am I doing it wrong or I should call [file_validate_extensions](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_validate_extensions/7) directly inside validation function

Comment: Try passing a string with a space separated list of allowed extensions.

Comment: Yep the function says the first arg to `file_validate_extensions()` should be _"A string with a space separated list of allowed extensions._

Comment: OK, thanks, now it seems to work, but I don't see any errors. Maybe because I have 3 different forms on single page.